# face detection for matlab

Tags: matlab, face-detection, matlab-cvst

i searched face detection for matlab to my project.
i found one:
http://people.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/kienzle/fdlib/fdlib.htm

i downloaded the source code, but it didn't work, i got that error from matlab:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'fdmex' for input arguments of type
>   'uint8'.
>
> Error in ==> tinytest at 10 s = fdmex(x', threshold);

the main script is:

```
x = imread('geeks.jpg');

% decision threshold.
% change this to a smaller value, if too many false detections occur.
% change it to a larger value, if faces are not recognized.
% a reasonable range is -10 ... 10.
threshold = 0; 

imagesc(x); hold on; colormap gray;
s = fdmex(x', threshold);

for i=1:size(s,1)
    h = rectangle('Position',[s(i,1)-s(i,3)/2,s(i,2)-s(i,3)/2,s(i,3),s(i,3)], ...
      'EdgeColor', [1,0,0], 'linewidth', 2);
end    

axis equal; 
axis off
```

can you find the error?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of matlab, it looks like the `fdlib`, comes with a `.dll`, rename it to `.mexw32` or whatever your host machine desires.  You can determine this by running:

```
>> mexext

mexw32
```

on the Matlab command prompt.  Use the mex extension and rename the `fdmex.dll` to `fdmex.mexw32`, or whatever `mexext` returns and it should run flawlessly.

If I run in on my Windows XP machine, I get that beautiful picure:

[image]

However, if you do not have a 32 bit machine, the author of the software writes on the [link in the question](http://people.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/kienzle/fdlib/fdlib.htm):

> Please note that all builds were optimized for Intel Pentium CPUs. If
> you would like to run it on a different platform, or have any other
> questions, please let me know.

He has a link to his profile and email, so I recommend contacting him for a 64 bit version of the executable.

Comment: i changed the .dll to .mexw64, but i got another error:

??? Invalid MEX-file 'C:\ran\Dropbox\IST
Project\face detection\face\fdmex.mexw64':
‏‏C:\ran\Dropbox\IST Project\face
detection\face\fdmex.mexw64 אינו חוקי
ביישום Win32‏.

Error in ==> tinytest at 11
s = fdmex(x', threshold);

Comment: @user2299317, if you are using 64 bit windows, then you'll need a 64 bit dll.  fdmex.dll is a 32 bit DLL.  Sounds like you'll need to recompile the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I see a uint8 error and a grayscale image, its a red flag to me that I need to do

```
colorImg=imread('imageName.jpg') 

% Even if the image is grayscale, if its png or jpg, 
% it will load in as a color image almost exclusively

img=rgb2gray(colorImg)
```

If you look at the img output, you will notice now its of type double instead of uint8 :)

If that doesn't work, hopefully macduffs will, mine just seems easier if that actually does fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of Matlab with the Computer Vision System Toolbox installed, you can use `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` system object to detect faces in images.